# gcov on larger projects (static libraries, ...)

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, build-process, code-coverage, gcov

I'm working on larger project which has the following directory layout:

```
Source
 MyA
  aa.cpp
  ab.cpp
  ac.cpp
 MyB
  ba.cpp
  bb.cpp
  bc.cpp
 MyTest
  testaa.cpp
  testab.cpp
  testac.cpp
  testba.cpp
  testbb.cpp
  testbc.cpp
  main.cpp
Build
 MyA
  aa.o
  ab.o
  ac.o
  libMyA.a (static library)
 MyB
  ba.o
  bb.o
  bc.o
  libMyB.a (static library)
 MyTest
  testaa.o
  testab.o
  testac.o
  testba.o
  testbb.o
  testbc.o
  MyTest (executable)
```

After compiling with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` I execute the MyTest application inside the Build/MyTest directory. As expected there are *.gcno and *.gcda files inside the Build directory. After running gcov inside the MyTest directory different *.gcov files are produced but unfortunately not for everything inside MyA and MyB, although every function is called inside this two libraries. Tried different options but somehow I'm unable to create useful (means correct) *.gcov files with this layout.

If I copy every cpp inside one directory and repeat the steps everything works as expected and the coverage analysis is perfect.

Answer (score 10):

1. You must specify source files as absolute paths to g++/gcc. Don't use relative paths with ".." or like "foo/bar.cpp", else you'll get errors like "geninfo: WARNING: no data found for XXXX".
2. Don't include any header files on the command line to g++/gcc. Else you'll get "stamp mismatch with graph file" errors.

So, following should work when having multiple directories:

```
g++ --coverage -DDEBUG -g3 heyo.cpp /app/helper/blah.cpp /app/libfoo/foo.cpp -o program

./program

lcov --directory . --capture --output-file app.info

genhtml --output-directory cov_htmp app.info
```

Or, if you're in a Makefile that uses relative paths already, it's convenient to use:

```
g++ --coverage -DDEBUG -g3 $(abspath heyo.cpp helper/blah.cpp ../foo/bar/baz.cpp) -o program
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my case. Thanks a lot. I guess I underrated `lcov` before.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to keep your directory structure, you need to run gcov once inside each source file folder, but use the `-o` option to tell gcov where the data files are.

I think it should be like this:

```
gcov -o ../../Build/MyA *.cpp
```

I have a project with a similar source file structure, but I let the compiler dump object files etc into the source folders.  I then run gcov multiple times from the root folder, once for each source file, but I specify the relative path of the source file and use the `-o` option to specify the relative folder like this:

```
gcov -o Source/MyA Source/MyA/aa.cpp
```

Comment: I assume you're calling gcc/g++ from your root directory as well then? If I just use the -o option from any directory all my *.gov files contain lot of /*EOF*/ altough all paths are correctly set. Probably my main problem is that the build system (qmake) calls the compiler from different locations.

Comment: @azraiyl: I'm using scons to build the project, so I'm not entirely sure, but, yes, I think scons uses relative paths to the source files.

Answer (score -2):

If you performed your product or application testing thoroughly and manually and spent lot of effort on it. If your objective is to get code coverage report using lcov and gcov but by mistake deleted gcno files. You can regenerate gcno files by recompiling the code but it will be generated with new timestamp and gcov reports error saying "stamp mismatch with graph file" and no code coverage report will be generated. This will result in all your testing effort getting wasted.

There is a shortcut to still generate the code coverage report. This is just a workaround and should not be relied upon all the time. Its recommended to preserve *.gcno files till your testing completes.

Note down your gcc version(gcc -v) and download its source code from one of the mirror sites
Eg - ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/gnu/sourceware/gcc/releases/gcc-4.4.6/gcc-4.4.6.tar.bz2

After extracting downloaded file, gcc the folder structure will be as follows
gcc-4.4.6
gcc-4.4.6/gcc

If you directly go inside gcc-4.4.6/gcc and try to do ./configure and compile(make) from there then you will encounter below problem
build/genmodes -h > tmp-modes.h
/bin/sh: build/genmodes: No such file or directory

Solution is do ./configure and make from gcc-4.4.6 and no errors will be shown related to genmodes. This will compile all modules including gcc. You may have to install mpfr and gmp modules which are needed by gcc if any error shown by ./configure

goto gcc-4.4.6/gcc/gcov.c and comment below lines and then recompile with above command

```
/*  if (tag != bbg_stamp)
    {
      fnotice (stderr, "%s:stamp mismatch with graph file\n", da_file_name);
      goto cleanup;
    }*/
```

Example path of new gcov binary after compilation is gcc-4.4.6/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/gcov

Place this binary in /usr/bin and regenerate code coverage report with command as shown in below example
lcov --capture --directory ./ --output-file coverage.info ; genhtml coverage.info --output-directory /var/www/html/coverage

Now you should not get "stamp mismatch with graph file" error and you will get code coverage report properly

Comment: Lots of useful information but does not answer the original question.